# What Microsoft.AstNetCore.SpaServices.Extension version has UseHsts method or alternative method that is compatible with .Net Framework 4.61?

Tags: asp.net-core, .net-core, .net-framework-version, asp-net-core-spa-services

I have a .Net Core 3.1 web application. Since I have to communicate to a legacy service using .Net Remoting, I decided to change the TargetFramework to 4.61. This has caused error with (IApplicationBuilder)app.UseHSTS(). So, I updated my referenced version of Microsoft.AspNetCore.SpaServices.Extension to 2.2.0. However, UseHSTS is not available with it. Is there an alternative solution?

Comment: ASP.NET Core 3 will not work on .NET Framework. The only supported version of ASP.NET Core that will still run on the .NET Framework is version 2.1. So you would have to downgrade.

Comment: this [method is .net core](https://apisof.net/catalog/Microsoft.AspNetCore.Builder.HstsBuilderExtensions.UseHsts(IApplicationBuilder)) only